# 'dotenv' module not found in a python3.7 Telegram Bot hosted in PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, dotenv

I am trying to install my *TelegramBot* based on **Aiogram** on **PythonAnywhere** servers.
I setup the environment based on **python3.7**
I installed my dependencies with:

`pip install -r requirements.txt --user`

I set up the environment and launched it with:

```
virtualenv env
. env/bin/activate
```

But once I launch my app this is the result with an error apparently on **load_dotenv**:

```
(env) 22:35 ~ $ python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import dispatcher
  File "lib/dispatcher.py", line 2, in <module>
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
```

Any ideas why on PythonAnywhere server the **python-dotenv** library seems not working properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the correct path to follow:

```
virtualenv -p python3 env

. env/bin/activate

pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Otherwise there was a confusion also in the python versions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `pip install -r requirements.txt` with the environment activated

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing two ways of installing packages.  `pip install` with the `--user` flag installs packages outside the virtualenv.  So you should run

```
. env/bin/activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
python3 main.py
```

If it still doesn't work, perhaps you don't have `dotenv` in your `requirements.txt` file?  Try doing

```
pip3 install dotenv
```

...and see if that helps.

Comment: The execution  `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` without `--user` inside virtualenv provokes this 

`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 't
op_level.txt'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.` or this `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/
usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/__pycache__/six.cpython-37.pyc'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.`

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem, and it looks like you've worked it out too at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59387856/32846.  When you created your virtualenv you implicitly created one using Python 2.7.  That meant that `pip3` and `python3` referred to programs that were outside the virtualenv.  TBH once you're in a virtualenv, you can just use `pip` and `python` without a version number at the end -- it will always use the version that you specified with `-p` when you created it.